# Order list of frames into new frame

Tags: r, list

I went trough the forum, but I cannot find excatly what I need to and I am not able to do.
I have this example data

```
A<-c(1,4,2,6,9,-5,-2,-5)
B<-c(-4,-1,4,10,3.5,2.9,-1.4,0.5)
AA<-data.frame(A,B,C,D)
C<-c(3,1.3,5.4,-4.3,5.5,2.5,-6.4,8.2)
D<-c(-2.4,-4.3,2.4,5.4,1.2,9.3,7.4,-4.1)
E<-c(0.4,2.4,5.6,2.8,4.5,2.9,3.3,8.1)
BB<-data.frame(C,D,E,G)
colnames(BB)<-c("A","B","C","D")
G<-c(1.4,2.5,-3.2,-6.3,8.2,-7.4,-0.3,1.1)
CC<-data.frame(E,G,A,B)
colnames(CC)<-c("A","B","C","D")
L<-list(AA,BB,CC)
L
```

I want to order it by one of the variables, I did this

```
ordered<-lapply(L,function(x) x[order(x$B,decreasing=TRUE),])
ordered
```

But the problem is that this solution is order each frame separately. 
What I need to is a new frame where are ordered data from whole list.
It means the ordered values (by B in this case) in columns and the information about where is this variable from (which list and row in the list) in rows.
It will be like this

```
              A    B    C    D
[[1]] [[4]]   6    10  -4.3  5.4
[[2]] [[6]]   2.5  9.3  2.9  -7.4
```

In this case

And so on,
NOTE: I have some NA's in the original data, so I hope the NA's will stay down.
Any advice or approach to do it?
Thanks

Comment: The question was edited because of the wrong source data. Now it is clear I hope. Thanks

Comment: I wrote a simple way to do this for your first data set you've posted, but I didn't check your new updates. If you want I can post the solution for the previous data set...

Comment: Theres is no `Profit_L_2` here, but you still parse it into `frame`

Comment: @David Arenburg My mistake, it is edited. Yeah you can post it, I will try to change it to work with this data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I reopened this question because I couldn't go trough for 1 week. I would like to please you for help with this edited question. The question is same as you showed me but for a bit different data (which I cannot deal with this way). Thank you a lot

Comment: @DavidArenburg Can I please you for undeleting your last answer with your solution? I found way how to transform my data to work with your solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: So you want to bring the data frames together into one and then order that one data frame by column B?

Comment: Yes, excatly but I need the information about the root of combination (where is it from) like is it in example. I have huge dataset, so it should be dynamic

Comment: Undeleted, but not sure it will help you with your new data

Comment: I transform this data trough unlist to vector a than back to frames. It should work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
dat <- suppressWarnings(data.frame(sapply(names(L[[1]]) , function(x) unlist(L)[grep(x, names(unlist(L)))])))
dat$Location <- paste(paste0("[[", rep(seq_len(length(L)), each = unique(sapply(L, nrow))), "]]"), paste0("[[", rep(seq_len(unique(sapply(L, nrow))), length(L)), "]]"))
dat <- dat[order(-dat$B), ]
```

Which gives

```
      A    B    C    D    Location
4   6.0 10.0 -4.3  5.4 [[1]] [[4]]
14  2.5  9.3  2.9 -7.4 [[2]] [[6]]
21  4.5  8.2  9.0  3.5 [[3]] [[5]]
15 -6.4  7.4  3.3 -0.3 [[2]] [[7]]
12 -4.3  5.4  2.8 -6.3 [[2]] [[4]]
3   2.0  4.0  5.4  2.4 [[1]] [[3]]
5   9.0  3.5  5.5  1.2 [[1]] [[5]]
6  -5.0  2.9  2.5  9.3 [[1]] [[6]]
18  2.4  2.5  4.0 -1.0 [[3]] [[2]]
11  5.4  2.4  5.6 -3.2 [[2]] [[3]]
17  0.4  1.4  1.0 -4.0 [[3]] [[1]]
13  5.5  1.2  4.5  8.2 [[2]] [[5]]
24  8.1  1.1 -5.0  0.5 [[3]] [[8]]
8  -5.0  0.5  8.2 -4.1 [[1]] [[8]]
23  3.3 -0.3 -2.0 -1.4 [[3]] [[7]]
2   4.0 -1.0  1.3 -4.3 [[1]] [[2]]
7  -2.0 -1.4 -6.4  7.4 [[1]] [[7]]
9   3.0 -2.4  0.4  1.4 [[2]] [[1]]
19  5.6 -3.2  2.0  4.0 [[3]] [[3]]
1   1.0 -4.0  3.0 -2.4 [[1]] [[1]]
16  8.2 -4.1  8.1  1.1 [[2]] [[8]]
10  1.3 -4.3  2.4  2.5 [[2]] [[2]]
20  2.8 -6.3  6.0 10.0 [[3]] [[4]]
22  2.9 -7.4 -5.0  2.9 [[3]] [[6]]
```

Comment: Thumbs up! I have to learn a lot, nice code. But it is on higher level than I am, so I won't be able to transform it for new data yet. BUt thanks

Comment: Thanks, it will be better. Have a nice day

Comment: After hours of working I realised that this solution doesn't work in case where number of rows in individual data.frames in list are different. I wasnt able to understand the results, but now I see it. It is repeating the same number of rows from first matrix.              1: In rep(seq_len(length(L)), each = unique(sapply(L, nrow))) :
  first element used of 'each' argument
2: In seq_len(unique(sapply(L, nrow))) :
  first element used of 'length.out' argument                         Any advices how to solve this problem?